# Pandas Dataframes values count over few columns with aggfunc=sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv dataset imported correctly, cleaned, NA values as required etc. i.e (dataset is far larger - name may contain same names as well as date)

```
NAME    SHIFT  DEP1  DEP2  DEP3  DAY
COLLINS AM     1     1     0.5   01/02/2016
JOHNS   PM     0.5   NA    0.5   02/02/2016
SMITH   AM     1     0.5   NA    01/02/2016
RUBBER  AM     NA    1.5   1     03/02/2016
COLLINS PM     NA    1     NA    02/02/2016
```

It shows number of overtimes and it lengths. What I need to achieve is the count of how many times people took overtime on AM shift or PM shift across ALL departments.
So for example (as in the table above)
AM shift had 7 overtimes and PM 3. I don't want to know who, when and why - doesn't matter.
I have tried pivot tables, count, values_count etc. and every time I receive entire dataframe with nested columns headings.
Should I use extra pyhton magic and iterate over each DEP - count non NA values and then sum them up and group by SHIFT?
I apologise for the style of the question but pandas documentation are bit vague and I'm a beginner in this subject
ps. so far I have found out much easier to import dataset to Excel and within 2 minutes I get the an answer I needed :(. there must be a better way to do this in pandas :)

EDIT.1

Every of those methods returns a count INCLUDING NA values... :(

EDIT.2

I HAVE isolated the problem - why your code `notnull()` drops NA but in my pandas it literally doing nothing (I got a dataframe with ONLY TRUE values)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) for creating mask and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with double `sum` first is [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and second is [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (df[['DEP1','DEP2','DEP3' ]].notnull())
    DEP1   DEP2   DEP3
0   True   True   True
1   True  False   True
2   True   True  False
3  False   True   True
4  False   True  False

print (df[['DEP1','DEP2','DEP3' ]].notnull().groupby([df.SHIFT]).sum())
       DEP1  DEP2  DEP3
SHIFT                  
AM      2.0   3.0   2.0
PM      1.0   1.0   1.0

df = df[['DEP1','DEP2','DEP3' ]].notnull().groupby([df.SHIFT]).sum().sum(axis=1)
print (df)
SHIFT
AM    7.0
PM    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Another solution (thanks [jeremycg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932489/pandas-dataframes-values-count-over-few-columns-with-aggfunc-sum/40932656#comment69076257_40932656) ) with [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
print (df.groupby('SHIFT')[['DEP1', 'DEP2','DEP3']].count())
       DEP1  DEP2  DEP3
SHIFT                  
AM        2     3     2
PM        1     1     1

df = df.groupby('SHIFT')[['DEP1', 'DEP2','DEP3']].count().sum(axis=1)
print (df)
SHIFT
AM    7
PM    3
dtype: int64
```

You can also first select by subset and then apply `count`:

```
print (df[['DEP1','DEP2','DEP3' ]].groupby([df.SHIFT]).count())
       DEP1  DEP2  DEP3
SHIFT                  
AM        2     3     2
PM        1     1     1

df = df[['DEP1','DEP2','DEP3' ]].groupby([df.SHIFT]).count().sum(axis=1)
print (df)
SHIFT
AM    7
PM    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: you can use .count to avoid having to use the mask - `df.groupby('SHIFT')[['DEP1', 'DEP2','DEP3']].count().sum(1)`

Comment: Thank you, I add it to answer.

Comment: @jezrael can you explain why a double sum?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy - I try explain more, is it better?

Comment: jezrael - your answer looks fine but I cross checked it with Excel and got different results :( Because excel giving me a full insight into data I tend to trust it more than "behind the scenes" pandas magic... I will investigate where the problem is and mark your answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, good idea. if think it is good idea, send me your real data to my email in my profile. Your data looks confidental, but it will be anonymized I can try find problem. Nice day!

Comment: @jezrael - no email showing on your profile or I can;t see it :(